# Arrays containing enumerations with associated values

Tags: swift

```
enum ConditionType {
    case Normal
    case Sick
    case Plagued
    case Poisoned(Double)
    case Drunk(Double)
    case Healing(Double)
    case Starving
    case NearDeath(Double)
    case Sleepy
}

var conditions: [ConditionType]

func addCondition(condition: ConditionType) {
    if conditions.contains(condition) == false {
        conditions.append(condition)
    }
}
```

In the "if conditions.contains(condition) == false {" line above I am getting the following error:

Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of '(ConditionType)'. What is the deal here? If I remove the associated values from the enum elements, then it compiles just fine.

I am running XCode 7.0 Beta 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `ConditionType` equatable and crate an op== that explains whether just the types need to match for them to be the same or if the contained values also need to match.